structural identifiability of ordinary differential equations is preserved when adding terms independent of parameters
Assume I have an ordinary differential equation of the form:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t,\Theta), \ x(0) = x_0
\end{equation*}
with $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^l \to \mathbb{R}^n$ being locally Lipschitz continuous.
And further assume, that this system is globally structurally identifiable with respect to the parameter set $\Theta$. Meaning that for a given trajectory $x(t):[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ that solves the above ODE, it is possible to infer exactly which parameters $\Theta$ were used.
Now, I was wondering if I have  a function $g(x,t): \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that is also locally Lipschitz, and maybe such that it doesn't shrink the maximal interval of existence of solutions. Is the system
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t,\Theta) + g(x,t), x(0) = x_0
\end{equation*}
still globally structurally identifiable ? Or does this only hold if $g$ only depends on $t$ or only on $x$ ?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions !

I think this is not true, at least for the case when $g$ only depends on $t$. Assume $\dot{x}=f(x,t,\Theta)=h(x,\Theta)+u(t)$ where $u$ is sufficiently exciting such that the system is structurally identifiable. Assume further that if $u$ were identical zero its not sufficiently exciting. Then $g(t)=-u(t)$ destroys structural identifiability. Maybe if $g$ depends only on $x$, but it would surprise me.
